# Postgres streaming replication system requirements

Tags: postgresql, replication

I currently have a server setup where my application together with the PostgreSQL database are hosted there. Because the data is really sensitive for our business and we could not afford a disaster scenario I was thinking, as a first step, to setup streaming replication to another server.

The current server has 64GB ram and it handles the ~200tps pretty well. If I am to setup another one for replication does it have to be 'that' big? What if I use a smaller machine e.g. 16GB ram for the slave in order to cut costs? Will this impact performance?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert but if you don't use the slave for queries, the RAM should be just fine as you are only doing "inserts" there.

Comment: Yes I want the slave only to be 'up to date' with the master. Only inserts and deletes will be performed there.

Answer (score 0):

since it will be in a read only mode, the server will be able to handle it. But be careful with your network speed that will carry all the changes in the master to the slave.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack overflow, check out the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer